# How to set marginTop on LinearLayout with java for Android?

Tags: android, margin, android-linearlayout

I am trying to set the marginTop of a LinearLayout with java for my Android app. I keep on getting "force quits" all the time. This is my code:

```
    LinearLayout lay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
    LayoutParams lp = lay.getLayoutParams();
    lp.setMargins(10, 20, 30, 40);
    lay.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

What am I doing wrong ?

This is what i get in my logcat:

```
01-12 18:50:16.237: D/AndroidRuntime(482): Shutting down VM
01-12 18:50:16.237: W/dalvikvm(482): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
01-12 18:50:16.237: E/AndroidRuntime(482): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-12 18:50:16.247: E/AndroidRuntime(482): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nu.katterevyn/nu.katterevyn.StartActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-12 18:50:16.247: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
01-12 18:50:16.247: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
01-12 18:50:16.247: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please post logcat stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code

```
LinearLayout lay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)lay.getLayoutParams();
lp.setMargins(10, 20, 30, 40);
lay.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change `LayoutParams` to `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` and `lp.setMargins(0, top, 0, 0);`. Also, specify a unit for your margins ex: `dp, px`.

Comment: sorry u don't need to specify a unit, it's by default pixel as pointed here in the doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#setMargins(int, int, int, int)

Comment: Okay, thank you. But it says that getLayoutParams() not can be converted into LinearLayout.LayoutParams, and i cant even run the code. This is what I have:

LinearLayout lay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = lay.getLayoutParams();

Comment: It could be that the `LayoutParams` that you're getting back is not a `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` object. The type of `LayoutParams` object depends on the parent layout, so if your `LinearLayout` is inside a `RelativeLayout`, you would need `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

Answer (score 0):

To specify unit to dp You can:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
a.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
return (size * metrics.densityDpi) / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;
```